# Writing set of functions that will use data stored elsewhere

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm writing a set of python functions that will parse addresses with the help of contextual data, in this case, lists of all towns and zip codes within my state, loaded using the json module. I know how to open, access, and use these data, however currently I am under the impression that if I were to add the code to access these data at the beginning of the file with these functions, then every time the function is called, it will re-open the data. Example below:

```
import json

with open('path') as f:
    towns = json.load(f)

with open('otherpath') as f:
    zips = json.load(f)

def address_parser(string):
    "my code here"
```

If I import the 'address_parser' function for use in another program, will it only load the data once, or will it re-load every time the function is called?

Thanks!

Comment: Without seeing how your code is structured, I'm not sure what the issue is? If you load the list of data into some python variable with the json module, then you'll have a variable in memory with all the data. It won't be re-reading from the json file each time you access the variable, just when you load the data.

Comment: load them once on first-usage, then cache in-memory for later re-use. of course, this'd only be useful if you actually USE the data multiple times in a single script run. if you don't, then the cache will be pointless - you'd have to load everything each time.

Comment: I edited the question with an example and to be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in a module body that is not in the `def`s or `class`es will be only once - at the module import time.

---

However if your module can be used without loading all of the data, and importing the data is costly, you can use lazy loading:

```
towns = None

def _load_towns():
    global towns
    with open('path') as f:
        towns = json.load(f)

def address_parser(...):
    # load if towns is None
    if towns is None:
        _load_towns()
```

Now the contents will not be loaded at the start-up time, but at the very first time that `address_parser` is called

Comment: Awesome, this is perfect. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

If the code block you have posted is in a file that is imported, the data is read only once, when you first import the file. Here's a trivial  example. File convert.py:

```
def to_euro(pounds):                             # function to use context data
   return pounds * exchange_rate

exchange_rate = input("Today's exchange rate: ") # read the context data
```

And using it:

```
>>> import convert
Today's exchange rate: 0.85       # the reading of the context data
>>> convert.exchange_rate
0.85                              # which was input when the convert module was loaded
>>> convert.to_euro( 10)          # uses the context data
8.5
>>>
```

the conversion data is stored in the convert module global namespace. The first time you import it, you'll be asked for exchange_rate. The next time, you won't, because the module is already imported and convert.exchange_rate is defined. (next time meaning another `import convert` in some other part of your Python program)

Realisticaly, you'd quietly read a file of exchange rates or whatever that's maintained by other parts of your system.

Another way would be to make Converter a class, obtain the context data when the constructor `__init__` is called, and store it as `self.context`. Use `self.context` in methods of the class that you call repeatedly. If you only ever create one instance, you'll only read the context data once. For the advanced student: make the context data into a class attribute, not an instance attribute, so it gets read only once even if you create multiple converter instances.